# Number of Mondays Falls on the First of the month

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, unix, gnu

I want a command line can display **number of Monday(s) which fall(s) on the first of the month in a given year** without using `sed` or `awk` commands

I have this command that display the first date of the current month

`date -d "-0 month -$(($(date +%d)-1)) days"`

Comment: Welcome! Is this bash ? or sh ? please edit question and add tag. If you don't know, open a terminal and type `echo $SHELL` (is probably bash). But I'm afraid you are picking the wrong tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `date`, you can read input from a file (or standard input):

```sh
printf '%s\n' 2021-{01..12}-01 | date -f- +%u | grep -c 1
```

This prints dates for the first of each month in a year, then formats them as "weekday" (where `1` is "Monday"), then counts the number of Mondays.

To parametrize the year, replace `2021` with a variable containing the year; wrapped in a function:

```sh
mondays() {
    local year=$1
    printf '%s\n' "$year"-{01..12}-01 | date -f- +%u | grep -c 1
}
```

Comment: Thing of beauty =}

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop, this can be accomplished as follows.

```
for mon in {01..12}; do date -d "2021-$mon-01" +%u; done | grep -c 1
```

**Breakdown**

- We iterate through the numbers `01` to `12` representing the months.
- We call `date` passing in the custom date value with the first date of each month in the year. We use `+%u` to return the day of week where `1` represents Monday.
- Lastly we count the number of `1`s using `grep -c` or `grep --count`

Note, the desired year has been hard coded as `2021`. The current year can be used as:

```
for mon in {01..12}; do date -d "$(date +%Y)-$mon-01" +%u; done | grep -c 1
```

This can also all be put into a function and the desired year passed in as an argument:

```
getMondays() {
  for mon in {01..12}; do date -d "$1-$mon-01" +%u; done | grep -c 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it as:

```sh
for ((i=1,year=2021,mondays=0; i< 12; i++)) { 
    if [ $(date -d "$i/1/$year" +%u) -eq 1 ]
    then  
        let "mondays++" 
    fi 
} 
echo "There are $mondays Mondays in $year."
```

That said, I like Mushfiq's answer. Quite elegant.